# Compiling Opa programs takes a very long time

Tags: opa

I just started learning Opa so please bear with me if my question is naive.

I'm following Opa book (found in binary package).  Chapter 1 went so fine and smooth.  Now when I try to build binary for chapter 2 (hello_wiki) on Linux, it takes a lot for my beefy laptop (Thinkpad T61) to finish the job.

```
[bahman@bleda hello_wiki]$ time opa hello_wiki.opa 
...
real    1m36.442s
user    1m34.497s
sys     0m4.540s
```

Is it normal?  If yes, how do you folks develop/test your programs?

TIA,

--
Bahman

Answer (score 1):

No, it' not normal, it should takes only a few seconds.

Are you using the latest stable version, Build 687 (`opa --version`)?

**Update:**

Indeed, there is a problem with this hello_wiki, with the line:

```
db /wiki: stringmap(Template.default_content)
```

We will check what's going one. Keep in touch.

Comment: Just tried build 652 the difference is marginal -only 2 seconds.  Please let me know if you need any more information about my setup to crack this issue.  Thanks.

Comment: I confirm there is problem with this hello_wiki.opa Something related to db `/wiki: stringmap(Template.default_content)`. Other examples like the chat on the homepage should compile in a few seconds, can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, 'hello_chat' worked like a charm.  Haven't tried others yet.  Is there any workaround?

Comment: More than a workaround, it's an advice: use a simpler type than this `Template.default_content`. This type became too "big" for the db engine (optim in progress). We may update the doc with a more reasonable example.